# OS X ending - character when viewing source

Tags: macos, mail.app

To view an email's source code in Mail.app, you can press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ option</kbd>  <kbd>U</kbd> . However, the source view is cut off every line on a certain character. Changing a line like this:

```
<img src=3D"https://phs-proto.ehv.campus.philips.com//mail/btn-bottom-left.gif" height=3D"3" width=3D"3" alt=3D"" border=3D"0" style=3D"display: block; width:3px; height:3px;" />

<img src=3D"https://phs-proto.ehv.campus.philips.com//mail/btn-b=
ottom-left.gif" height=3D"3" width=3D"3" alt=3D"" border=3D"0" sty=
le=3D"display: block; width:3px; height:3px;" />
```

Notice the `=` sign at the end of the lines. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is in a section of the email marked with

```
--_000_7ACBD9F85F865846BB187E5B1529E52F25B26392F5LBCPLCYVMB002_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Where the first line would be a different long series of digits.

In this case = just marks a line continuation, To get the text delete it and the following CR and LF characters.

The encoding is needed as email as per [RFC5322](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) says

> Lines of characters in the body MUST be limited to 998 characters,
> and SHOULD be limited to 78 characters, excluding the CRLF.

The encoding is quoted-printable and that is defined in [RFC2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7)

> (Soft Line Breaks) The Quoted-Printable encoding
> REQUIRES that encoded lines be no more than 76
> characters long.  If longer lines are to be encoded
> with the Quoted-Printable encoding, "soft" line breaks
> must be used.  An equal sign as the last character on a
> encoded line indicates such a non-significant ("soft")
> line break in the encoded text.

The workaround is use a script to decode the MIME encapsulation